# Can I set the order of copied files using robocopy?

Tags: cmd, robocopy

For example I need newly created files were copied first (i.e. to copy files by date). 
This is my line of code using robocopy:

robocopy /mov /w:5 /is %source% %destination% *.cdc *.txt

Comment: This question is not clear to me. If you only want files on the source that are newer than files on the destination, the `/XN` or one of the other `/X?` switches may do what you want. I would question the use of `/IS`. What do you think `/IS` is doing?

Comment: Actually I am aware about each attribute. I just want to copy fresh files first. What is not clear? Guess I have figured it out: 
`for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (`dir "%source%" /A:-D /B /O:-D`) do (robocopy /mov /w:5 /is "%source%" "%destination%" "%%G")`